# How can I use a Pixhawk 4 power distribution board (PM07) to power an older pixhawk?

Tags: esc, power

I have the PM07 power distribution board designed for the Pixhawk 4 but I currently have a Pixhawk 2.8.4. On the data sheets I can clearly see a 5V output but I am not getting any power from those pins. I am able to get power to all ESCs and motors just fine.

[image]
[image]

Do the two 5V output pins not take power from the battery? Is the PM07 itself unable to output 5V without some other criteria being met? Am I wiring it wrong? I have tried connecting to the ground pin right under the 5V out pin and also the ground pins of the ESCs.

Answer (score 0):

The pins of the power ports on both the pixhawk 4 and pixhawk 2.8 are exactly the same. All you need to do is make a cable with one end that plugs into the PMO7 board (JST GH 6 PIN connector) and one end that plugs into the pixhawk 2.4.8 (DF13 6 PIN).